# Java - Count words in two documents

Tags: java, data-structures

3 - Now I have to see if there is any word in current file from above terms or not, if yes then I will count.

Now this is my problem, I stucked on step 3 :(

I have some idea how to count words with TreeMap (treemap.containskey etc.) but it would be global count not local count for each file :(

Any pseudo code?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to have one map for each file, e.g. stored in a map again.

Comment: Thanks, could you please be more precise?

Comment: @user552961: I was thinking something along the lines of a `Map<File, Map<String, Integer>>`

Answer (score 0):

it's unclear to me, but i'm assuming your "two documents" refers to **Document A** containing all possible terms of which you **are not** interested it the occurrence count, and **Document B** containing some or all of the terms of which you **are** interested in the occurrence count, provided they also appear in Document A.

I'm not sure that this is what you want but its my best guess from the way you've worded your question.

Your end result could be a Map (TreeMap if you prefer) where the string is the word, and the Integer is the occurrence count.

so you would firstly read through Document A doing a `map.put(word, 0);` for every word. each duplicated word would replace the existing entry in the map. You could test for existence first, but i don't think this would make much of a performance difference.

you have now completed your step 1 and 2.

now you need to read through your Document B and for every word:

1. check its existence in the map
2. if it exists, increment the value

ie: `if map.containsKey(word) map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1)`

you have now completed your step 3 and have a map containing only the words contained in Document A, and their occurrence count in document B.

If I've misunderstood your requirements I'm sure you could adapt this to fit.

**EDIT**

if you just want to count the words in one document, the pseudo code becomes:

```
for (word)
    if (map.containsKey(word))
        map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1)
    else
        map.put(word, 1)
```

ie, every word you hit you increment its count by one. if the word hasn't been hit before you initialise it in your map with one.

at the end of this process you have a map containing each word in the document and its occurrence count.

Comment: thanks you almost got my question :). I have more than 50 documents and I understood your first two steps they are pretty simple and clear. I could not understand your step three, could you please explain bit more? How can I count each file's words? Do I need to make two loops? first will run for all terms and second will check for the specific word in each file to count? I am sorry I am confused :(

Answer (score 0):

He asked kinda of the same thing in this topic: [Java loop and increment problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526989/java-loop-and-increment-problem/4528059#4528059)

Assuming you'll have one word on each line and the last line of the file contains "-1" to break the loop..

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, Integer> countedWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    String word = "";
    while (true) {
        word = scanner.nextLine();
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
            break;
        }
        if (countedWords.containsKey(word)) {
            numberOfWords = countedWords.get(word);
            countedWords.put(word, ++numberOfWords);
        } else {
            countedWords.put(word, 1);
        }
    }
    Iterator it = countedWords.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're method of terminating the loop the is a bit non-standard, `the end` is a valid input, instead just check if `nextLine()` returns null.

Comment: WOW, i can't believe i didn't see this before...your map is all wrong....it should be `<String,Integer>`....Did you even try this? `containsKey` will throw an error.

Comment: Better now? It kinda work same way. If I use map.get(key) it will return the value. If I use map.get(value) it will return the key..

Comment: I tried to make map.get(word) + 1 but didn't worked, even casting. Do you have any idea why? Maybe I didn't cast right..