# Java loop and increment problem

Tags: java, data-structures, loops

Can any one tell me what is the problem in my program?

```
String a[],b[];
int c[] = new int[b.length];

for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
        if (b[k].equals(a[j])) {
            c[k]++;
        } else {
            c[k] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have thousands of words stored in a `HashMap`. Now I want to check in every file that how many time one word occurred from `allWords`.

Can you point out mistake in my program or give me your idea that how I can do it?

Comment: What errors are you getting in your current implementation?  One possible mistake I see so far is that you never initialize `oneFileWords` or `allWords`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count words while reading your files and store on a Map already..
Assuming last word on file is "-1" and there's only one word in a line, even if the word is "happy birthday", I'd do something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, Integer> countedWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    String word = "";
    while (true) {
        word = scanner.nextLine();
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
            break;
        }
        if (countedWords.containsKey(word)) {
            numberOfWords = countedWords.get(word);
            countedWords.put(word, ++numberOfWords);
        } else {
            countedWords.put(word, 1);
        }
    }
    Iterator it = countedWords.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this line is resetting your counters unnecessarily:

```
newData[j] = 0;
```

Try removing it:

```
for (int j = 0; j < oneFileWords.length; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < allWords.length; k++) {
        if (allWords[k].equals(oneFileWords[j])) {
            newData[j]++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to keep a separate count for each word in each file then you will need to use two dimensional array.

```
int newData[][] = new int[oneFileWords.length][allWords.length];
```

You can then access it using `newData[j][k]`.

Comment: isn't it bad for performance? I used two dimensional array before and I couldn't increment it then I used another loop to sum it and it killed my program speed

Comment: @user552961: There's nothing intrinsically slow about two dimensional arrays. I would imagine it is the way you are using it that was making it slow. I don't know why you think you need an extra loop - just change `newdata[j]` to  `newdata[j, k]`.

Comment: @Mark Byers: *newData[j, k]* !? I don't know this kind of way to access two dimensional arrays in Java (Java 5 here that said).  You meant *newData[][]* and *new int[oneFileWords.length][allWords.length]* and you meants to access it using *newData[j][k]* instead of *newData[j,k]* ?  I'm not sure so I don't dare to edit your answer myself.

Comment: @SpoonBender: Sorry, you are probably correct - I didn't test it.

Comment: @SpoonBender can you give me your solution too? Thanks

Comment: @Mark Byers, when you will print two dimensional array, it will not give you the same output as I request in my question. It will only produce, e.g., 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 \n 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 \n 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 then I have to use another loop to sum all these values to get 1 file calculated words.

Comment: @user552961: I see now. You can eliminate one of the loops by using a set to determine membership. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: @user552961: I just pointed out that the syntax Mark Byers used (for two-dimensional arrays) in his unedited answer wasn't correct.  Both him and me now edited this answer so that it's using the correct syntax.